# How list indexing works in Jinja

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I have a simple `flask` application where I need to show 2 images in a `html` page, all the images are stored in a `static` folder

While rendering the `html` page I am passing image file names as a list and on `html` page I am using `jinja` logic to show the images

```
img_lst = [filename1, filename2]
return render_template("index.html", img_lst=img_lst)
```

I can easily loop over the list and show images using below logic

```
{% for image in img_lst %}
    <img src="{{url_for('static', filename=image)}}">
{% endfor %}
```

but if I index a particulr file from a list I am getting an error

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'img_lst' is undefined

<img src=" {{url_for('static', filename=img_lst[0])}}">
```

I want to individually access filenames from list instead of looping over

Comment: The problem must lie elsewhere, because provided no other context, then that should work.

Comment: Same, unable to reproduce given your code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't see any problem with your code above, but i'm guessing you need to force `flask` to reload templates, so `jinja2` will take in consideration your variable `img_lst` the next reload.

add this config below and let me know if it works:

```
app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True
```

#### Update

Your code works and i didn't get that error, so my guess probably you are working on **other view/template** and you forgot to pass `img_lst` in the context in render function.

Comment: Hi @cizario this didn't solved the problem, let me know if I have to share the whole code

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I found the issue there was one more default end point where I was rendering `index.html` and I forgot to pass `img_lst` variable